# how to get values of description list, with terms and descriptions in DOMXPath?

Tags: curl, web, web-scraping, web-crawler, domxpath

So far i get complete html of page now i want to get data of description list from that page.  i am new with web scraping so please help me out with this?

Here is html that i want to get.

```
<dl id="specs">

    <dt class="section">Keyboard</dt>
    <dt>Keyboard</dt>
    <dd>88 keys</dd>
    <dt>Touch Sensitivity</dt>
    <dd>Key Touch: 5 types, fixed touch</dd>
    <dt>Keyboard Mode</dt>

    <dt class="section">Sound Generator</dt>
    <dt>Piano Sound</dt>
    <dd>SuperNATURAL Piano Sound</dd>

</dl>
```

Comment: Actually i want to get text of <dt> and <dd>.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
/dl[id='specs']/dt[class='section']/(dt|dd)/text()
```

or

```
/dl[id='specs']/dt[class='section']/dt/text()
/dl[id='specs']/dt[class='section']/dd/text()
```

?

The first should give you all text nodes beneath dt and dd tags, while the latter give you text nodes separate for dt and dd nodes if that should be of any signification.

Comment: it didn't work. look i want to get dt text then the next dd text and after data i will store in database table.

Comment: If you want to do more than just getting the values, please update your question.

Comment: problem solved with another way. but still thanks for helping me out